# M3 model@uses: src to innerclass

Tags: rascal

Is there an easy way to translate the "src" loc of model@uses to a class?

The problem I am having is I tried to use the model@declarations to match and find the class by location, but matching between file:// and project:// (m3 model) is not 100% pure (ignoring .scheme), comparing

> begin.line >=

and

> end.line <=

still results in 2 classes, when a "src" line is in the innerclass.

To summarise: Is there a function that returns the class, e.g.

> loc classLoc = getClass( |home:///Workspaces/Rascal/src/Fruit.java|(150,1,<11,12>,<11,13>) );

That will return |java+class://Fruit|, having line 11 be a line in class Fruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Consider this example Java code:

```
public abstract class Fruit {

    private class X {

    }

    int main() {
        X x = new X();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and consider I stored the M3 model in `m` and take the use of X located at this source location `l = |home:///Workspaces/Rascal/rascal/src/org/rascalmpl/courses/example-project/src/Fruit.java|(150,1,<11,12>,<11,13>);`

Then this expression will tell you to which declaration the class points to:

```
rascal>cl = m@uses[l];
set[loc]: {|java+class:///Fruit/X|}
```

To find out in which other class this class is then nested we invert the containment relation and look up the parent of the nested class like so:

```
rascal>m@containment<to,from>[cl]
set[loc]: {|java+class:///Fruit|}
```

Comment: I understand this m@uses[l], but what I am trying to do is translate "l" to the class it belongs to, not which classes it uses. Is there a function like ( getClass( l ) ) and/or getMethod( l ) ?

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful in finding out if a class is an innerClass. Now suppose the innerclass is a builder-class, and I want to call the builderclass Z inside class X in another class Y. This gives a uses.src of class Y and the uses.name of class Z. If I use containment[z] it will give me X. What I want to get is the class Z instead.

Comment: @avk sounds like there is some confusion going on. At least I don't understand the question anymore. Perhaps you could change your question to give the code and the answer, and I could produce the query which produces it? Right now I believe the answer to your question is still `m@uses[l]` which gives you the fully qualified name of Z (in the context of your previous comment).

Comment: It is indeed confusing, and technically you answered my initial question, solving my immediate problem. Thank you.